# Entity Framework Include match relation with 1 table only and ignore all other foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am trying to include data from 2 tables

```
var foundAssetFunctionalLocation = _context.AssetFunctionalLocationServicePoint
            .Include(x => x.MeasuringPoints)
            .Include(x => x.Assets)
            .Where(x => x.ServicePointReference == "3053880001")
```

Asset table has Id of the MeasuringPoints and AssetFunctionalLocationServicePoint as foreign keys

I want to include records from Asset table based on MeasuringPoints id only because AssetFunctionalLocationServicePoint id can be null some time.

How can I modify my query to get that result? Currently it goes 0 records in Assets.

Currently I have these records in database.

[image]

Doing this also throws error "Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid."

```
var foundAssetFunctionalLocation = _context.AssetFunctionalLocationServicePoint
            .Include(x => x.MeasuringPoints.Select(y => y.Assets))
            .Where(x => x.ServicePointReference == "3053880001")
```

Comment: I used EF core with my .NET Core Web API using repository pattern and UOW (Unit of Work). I also faced the same issue and I had to explicitly load reference tables as below; 
                                                                                                       
 `_context.TableOne.Include(x => x.RefTable).ToList();
_context.TableTwo.Include(x => x.RefTable).ToList();`

Comment: Thank you for your response, what would be syntax in my case?

Comment: Refer [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

Comment: I get that error message. I have updated my question with details.

Comment: Can you share your dbContext and classes?